# Spring: relation data many-to-one

Tags: spring, orm, eclipselink

i have first entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_ONE")
public class TableOne implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TABLE_TWO_ID", nullable = false)
    private TableTwo tableTwoId;
```

and the second table entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_TWO")
public class TableTwo{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;
```

, but then after i compile , the result is :

**ERROR: column "table_two_id" does not exist**

I want to get ID from TableTwo.

Comment: Are you sure that your table TableOne has a column named TABLE_TWO_ID? Maybe TABLE_TWO_ID is the wrong column name

Comment: yes right, the coloumn table_two_id does not exist, how to connect with only ID column, what properties inside the @JoinColumn()

Answer (score 0):

Joincolumn annotation tells hibernate the foreign key join column name, in this case I guess it's ID.